# Archiving mails while this function is disabled

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I cannot archive my company emails as the IT disabled this function and they are deleted every 60 days.

[image]

Is there any other way that I can archive my emails? Save the .ost file every 59 days?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you'll need third-party tools. For example, the free [Backup Outlook Folders](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookFolderBackup/) utility. You'll need to run it periodically to make full backups of all selected folders. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: do i need administrative privileges to install it?

Comment: Nope. Perfectly installs for a limited user.